# how to download uploaded files?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with Php an Angular, I can upload files to local database and I can retrieve files information. i don't know how to retrieve the file itself and download it to my computer. can someone please help?
in database - column/type= id-int, name-varchar, mime-longblob, size-biginet, data-mediumblob, created-datetime

Php for retrieving files details:

```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hamatkin');

  mysqli_query($connection, "SET character_set_client = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection, "SET character_set_connection = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection, "SET character_set_results = utf8");

  if (!$connection) {
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }

  $query = "SELECT id, name, created FROM file";
  $queryResult = $connection->query($query);

  $queryResult2 = array();

  if ($queryResult === false) {
    die($connection->error);
  }

  if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()) {
      $queryResult2[] = $row;
    }
  }

  $queryResult3 = json_encode($queryResult2);

  echo json_encode($queryResult2);
```

controller:

"use strict";

```
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('allPriceOffersCtrl', function($scope,$route,$location,$http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/customers-tab/get-all-priceOffers.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = response.data;
        $scope.files = arr;
      })
      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      });

});
```

Html:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table  class="customer-list table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th>#</th> -->
        <th class="Column-Header"> מספר קובץ הצעת מחיר</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">שם הקובץ</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">תאריך</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in files ">
        <!-- <td>{{$index + 1}}</td> -->
        <td>{{ x.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.name}}</td>
        <td> {{ x.created}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Storing the files in database as blob elements?

Comment: @GeeK is that not good? I'm sorry I'm new with this...what do you suggest?

Comment: I hope my answer help, let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to upload the files to server and add a .htaccess to restrict access, rename the file to a serial number so two files with same name never override and store the path of the file inculding filename.extension (relative path from website), serialNo. as id and real-name of the file(with extension). populate the path as required and rename before downloading.

This [Example](http://www.lionblogger.com/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-php-save-the-path-in-mysql/) is some what relevant

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/uploading-files-to-the-server-using-php.aspx

Read this example, It'll explain in more details, still if you don't understand, give me your database structure and I'll explain it myself.

Comment: can we go to chat?

Comment: sure. Can we chat here? or email me at sherazahmed93@gmail.com

Comment: I don't know how to move to stackoverflow chat, I will send you an email now with my structure. thanks!

Comment: did you get my email?

Comment: are you still here?

Comment: Oh Yes, I'm sorry, I got busy with something, I've just replied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118933/discussion-between-tanyaa-and-geek).